# ShellExecute failing if spaces in Path

Tags: delphi, windows-xp, filepath, shellexecute

I have a Delphi application that uses ShellExecute to call a second Delphi Application on a button press.

The applications are stored on the same server, on the same network share.  Their paths are in the format:

```
const
   JobManager = 'Z:\Apps\Application 1\Application1.exe';
   FeeManager = 'Z:\Apps\Application 2\Application2.exe';
```

The call to ShellExecute is made as follows:

```
rh := FindWindow(PChar('TMF'), PChar('Edit Job Details'));
if rh = 0 then
begin
   ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', JobManager, nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   ...
```

As we have three office we have copies of the Apps folder on each office server.  Each server has the Apps folder on a share mapped to "Z:"

In one of the offices we have discovered a problem where the Applications cannot be found if the paths contain spaces.  As the applications are straight copies of each other, and work in the other offices the problem seems to be a machine setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you tried using double quotes? `ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('"Z:\Apps\Application 1\Application1.exe"'), nil, nil, 0);`

Comment: Show the code, and include the values of any variables passed to ShellExecute.

Comment: @RRUZ- We've tried adding quotes around the constant

Comment: It is very likely that in your (good) reduction of the problem to fit the Q&A format you have edited out some essential details. How exactly did you conclude that on that particular machine "spaces in the path" are the difference between working / not working? I find that suspect, can you confirm this with a trivial test app? Also, what does filemon say?

Comment: @Paul-Jan It's been tested by a quick recompile to remove the spaces and a rename of the affected folder on the problem machine.  This worked, but isn't a long term solution.  We haven't ascertained it this is a single machine or branch office problem.

Comment: ShellExecute returns an error code when it fails, the code does not seem to check it.

Comment: The fault is probably with the target app rather than shell execute call.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Do you have any details about ShellExecute errors?

Comment: @Dan - See 'return value' section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In your parameters. Try using 0 as Handle, `nil` instead of `open` (default) and `PChar(JobManager)`. double quotes around <path> are not needed at all AFAIK.

Comment: @Kobik looks like the PChar around the JobManager was the issue - can you set that as an answer so I can accept it?  On to the second issue...

Comment: @Dan - That doesn't make any sense. [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/String_Types#Using_Pointers.2C_Arrays.2C_and_String_Constants): *"You can also pass string constants to any function that takes value or const parameters of type PChar or PWideChar.."*. I believe you either posted fake code, or your problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: @Sertac For the majority of our PCs passing the JobManager constant without calling PChar works.  For this one office (one user?) PChar seems to be the solution, whilst not breaking the other users.

Comment: @Dan - Looking at the CPU window, a PChar cast around a string literal looks like effectively a nop. In any case, glad you've resolved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your `lpFile` parameter you should cast `JobManager` as `PChar`:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(JobManager), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Note that the `open` verb parameter is also not needed, and you could pass `nil` with the `lpOperation` parameter (default).

Answer (score 0):

It works with double quotes:

```
WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ExtractFilePath(application.ExeName) + '\winrar.exe A  "c:\BACKUP 2016\backup_"' .....
```