# VBA Shell command to open image in Microsoft Office Picture Manager

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using Microsoft Access I am trying to open a .jpg in Microsoft Office Picture Manager software using the Shell command but when the Sub is execute nothing happen. Could someone help with this?

```
Private Sub btnPhoto_Click()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.Recordset
    Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OIS.EXE"
    File = rs("PathPhoto")

    x = Shell(Path + " " + File, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the result (x) and paste & execute it in a command prompt? Does it work there?I _think_ the problem might be missing quotation marks around the executable, see this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893650/shellexecute-failing-if-spaces-in-path)

Comment: `x = Shell("""" & Path & """ """ & File & """", vbNormalFocus)` since any path which might contain a space needs to be quoted

Comment: Thank you Tim you were right the quotations were not correct. Now it works!